# Why we could omit “it is”?

Tags: ellipsis

Sentence 1: We try to help whenever **it is** possible.

Sentence 2: We try to help whenever possible.

Sentence 3: I should like to be back here by 10.30 if **it is** possible.

Sentence 4: I should like to be back here by 10.30 if possible.

I am wondering why we could omit "it is" in the above situations.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, "it is" is implied. Also in S3. and S4, use "would" instead of "should". Also I edited S4 as it looked like a missed copy/paste.

Comment: I am just wondering why we could omit "it is" in the situations.

Comment: "It" is used to point to a noun or action. If it is already obvious where one is pointing to (or what one is talking about), "it" may be skipped. So generally speaking, "It" and the pointed object are in not used in the same sentence (or section of a sentence).

Comment: There's no reason to suppose it's specifically the words **it is** that have been "deleted". The first example could be "fleshed out" as *"We try to help whenever **helping** is possible"*. *"It"* is just a convenient pronoun to reference whatever we hope might be possible (for "generic" terms, *that* or *this* would normally be just as acceptable), but it's stretching a point to say that *any* such reference is inherently necessary between *whenever* and *possible*. It's just something we often do.

Answer (score 4):

"It is" is a phrase used to remind a reader or listener of the subject being discussed. The examples you've given are short and the hearer probably remembers what you're talking about so it (the reminder) is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simply an example of an [abbreviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbreviation) of a common conditional phrase form. There are many similar examples.

- Use fresh tomatoes, when available.
- Visit Rome, if nearby.
- Smile, if happy.

This is done for concision when the result is unambiguous.

Answer (score -2):

"possible" is an adjective meaning that something can happen.
I always find it easier when you simplify the sentences to understand what is happening.
Sentence 1a: We help whenever possible. (take out "try to")
Possible in this case has to refer to help.

Sentence 4a: I will return if possible (replace "should like", which is perfectly correct British English, with "will", "be back" becomes "return" and take the time out, just to simplify the sentence). Possible refers to return.

Comment: How does this answer the question of "What makes it okay to omit ***it is*** in these sentences?"

Comment: Yes, it doesn't answer my question. I am wondering why we could omit "it is" in the situations.